# Render blocking scripts present only on mobile

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm experiencing a weird situation with respect to my wordpress site. I've worked on it eradicating all errors and I have a very decent 94/100 on PC but just 71/100 on mobile and the weird thing is, the render blocking scripts i see on mobile are more than the scripts i see on the PC.

Can anyone kindly help me and let me know why this is happening?

http://prntscr.com/d95npy - PC

http://prntscr.com/d95nuf - Mobile

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are loading all the `css` inside your `<head>` tag.
What PageSpeed is suggesting to you is to **Optimize CSS delivery**.

In order to achieve it, try to have a look at the following resources:

- [Optimize CSS Delivery](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/optimize-css-delivery.html)

> The ideal CSS setup would look something like this...
>
> - No more than one external CSS stylesheet of an reasonable size (less    than 75k or so)
> - Inline small CSS into HTML using style tags for above    the fold content
> - No @import calls for CSS No CSS in HTML things like    your divs or your h1s (in element CSS)

You should basicaly not import these CSS from external sources but include them instead inside your projet.

If you are looking for a more pragmatic approach, have a look at [pagespeed documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin to optimise delivery of css,

https://wordpress.org/plugins/above-the-fold-optimization/

This plugin is not a simple 'on/off' plugin. It is a tool for optimisation professionals and advanced WordPress users to achieve a Google Page Speed 100 Score.

Please check for AMP plugin for Google page rank.AMP is for mobile website optimisation.